# Python: read one word per line of a text file

Tags: file, search, python-2.7, cpu-word

Its not a proper code but I want to know if there is a way to search just one word w./o using .split() as it forms a list and i dont want that with this snippet:

```
f=(i for i in fin.xreadlines())
for i in f:
    try:
        match=re.search(r"([A-Z]+\b) | ([A-Z\'w]+\b) | (\b[A-Z]+\b) | (\b[A-Z\'w]+\b) | (.\w+\b)", i) # | r"[A-Z\'w]+\b" | r"\b[A-Z]+\b" | r"\b[A-Z\'w]+\b" | r".\w+\b"
```

Also can i make a reusable class module like this

```
class LineReader: #Intended only to be used with for loop
    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.fin=open(filename,'r')
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        line=self.fin.xreadline()
        return line.split()
```

where say f=LineReader(filepath)

and for i in f.**getitem**(index=line number 25) loop starts from there?
i dont know how to do that.any tips?

Comment: What do you want instead of a list? A generator? A function returning a new word every time it gets called?

Comment: output should be for example per line: word1 word2 word3.. just an o/p string

Comment: @Lennart lets say a simple text file is searched for particular pattern.only print 1 o/p per line. and can it be done through a class like given above?

Comment: What do you mean with word? In the first sample you search for blocks of uppercase letters and in de second sample all text that is not an whitespace. And what do you mean with search one word? Do you want the first word from the line?

Comment: @Lennart Yes just first word per line if it matches the pattern

Comment: You can get the first word using `line[:max(line.find(' '),0) or None]
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first word of a line:

```
line[:max(line.find(' '), 0) or None]
```

`line.find(' ')` searches for the first whitespace, and returns it. If there is no whitespace found it returns -1

`max( ... ), 0)` makes sure the result is always greater than 0, and makes -1 0. This is usefull because bool(-1) is True and bool(0) is False.

`x or None` evaluates to x if x != 0 else None

and finaly `line[:None]` is equal to `line[:]`, which returns a string identical to `line`

First sample:

```
with open('file') as f:
    for line in f:
        word = line[:max(line.find(' '), 0) or None]
        if condition(word):
            do_something(word)
```

And the class (implemented as a generator here)

```
def words(stream):
    for line in stream:
        yield line[:max(line.find(' '), 0) or None]
```

Which you could use like

```
gen = words(f)
for word in gen:
    if condition(word):
        print word
```

Or

```
gen = words(f)
while 1:
    try:
        word = gen.next()
        if condition(word):
            print word
    except StopIteration:
        break # we reached the end
```

---

But you also wanted to start reading from a certain linenumber. This can't be done very efficient if you don't know the lengths of the lines. The only way is reading lines and discarding them until you reach the right linenumber.

```
def words(stream, start=-1): # you could replace the -1 with 0 and remove the +1
    for i in range(start+1): # it depend on whether you start counting with 0 or 1
        try:
            stream.next()
        except StopIteration:
            break
    for line in stream:
        yield line[:max(line.find(' '), 0) or None]
```

Be aware that you could get strange results if a line would start with a space. To prevent that, you could insert `line = line.rstrip()` at the beginning of the loop.

Disclaimer: None of this code is tested